# How to source multiple files in shiny server?

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny, apply, lapply

I'm trying to load some code for the server file from a folder. I've tried the following approaches, but they didn't work.

```
sapply(list.files(pattern="[.]R$", path="R/", full.names=TRUE), source)
```

```
sourcefiles <- list.files(full.names=TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "[.]R$")
sapply(sourcefiles, source, chdir = TRUE)
```

```
lapply(list.files(pattern = "[.]R$", recursive = TRUE), source)
```

This code works, but I have to call them individually.

```
source(file.path("./R/modules/", "plot.R"),  local = TRUE)$value  

source(file.path("./R/modules/", "freq.R"),  local = TRUE)$value
```

I'm looking for a way to apply a function to loop through the files in the folder.

Comment: I think this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67764752/automate-a-series-of-actions-done-on-a-single-csv-file-to-all-csv-files-within/67765022#67765022

Comment: `sapply(list.files(pattern="[.]R$", path="R/", full.names=TRUE), source)` works in normal script. It has issues working in `shiny` I guess. Can you show your shiny code and show how and where you are using this?

Answer (score 1):

This code takes all the name of files in the home directory and filters the names that en in .R and maps source the ones that match.

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

list.files(path = '~') %>%
    str_subset('\\.R') %>% 
    map(~source(.x))
```

Comment: This seemed to work, but I'm not able to get it working in the shiny app.

Comment: I'm getting no error as the module doesn't seem it's connected when I run the shiny app.

Comment: Is piping `walk(~source(.x,  local = TRUE))`  instead of `map(~source(.x))` works?